# Why does Codepen.io not show a thumbnail / preview for this pen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

http://codepen.io/fauxnoir/pen/mJwBxm

```
AUDIO_FILE = 'http://matthiasdv.org/cdn/tracks/robbery_song'

CODECS = [ 'mp3' ]

stats = new Stats()
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'
stats.domElement.style.left = '0px'
stats.domElement.style.top = '0px'

# CONFIG
FORCE_INWARDS = 1000
RADIUS_INWARDS = 3000
FORCE_OUTWARDS = -200000
RADIUS_OUTWARDS = 400
NUM_PARTICLES = 800
PARTICLE_RADIUS_MULTIPLIER = 0.6
PARTICLE_MIN_MASS = 3.0
PARTICLE_MAX_MASS = 6.0



class Simulation

  @COLOURS = [
    '#030106'
  ]

  constructor: ->

    @physics = new Physics()
    @mouse = new Particle()
    @mouse.fixed = true
    @height = window.innerHeight
    @width = window.innerWidth

    @renderTime = 0
    @counter = 0

  setup: (full = yes) ->

    min = new Vector 0.0, 0.0
    max = new Vector @width, @height

    bounds = new EdgeBounce min, max

    @physics.integrator = new Verlet()

    center = new Vector(@width/2, @height/2)

    attraction = new Attraction center, RADIUS_INWARDS, FORCE_INWARDS
    repulsion = new Attraction center, RADIUS_OUTWARDS, 0
    collide = new Collision()

    # Dancer
    @dancer = new Dancer()
    @kick = @dancer.createKick {
      treshold: 0.2
      onKick: (mag) =>
        repulsion.strength = FORCE_OUTWARDS

        r = Random.item @physics.particles

        repulsion.target.x = r.pos.x
        repulsion.target.y = r.pos.y

      offKick: (mag) ->
        repulsion.strength = 0
    }


    max = if full then NUM_PARTICLES else 200

    for i in [0..max]
      p = new Particle (Random PARTICLE_MIN_MASS, PARTICLE_MAX_MASS)
      p.setRadius p.mass * PARTICLE_RADIUS_MULTIPLIER

      p.moveTo new Vector (Random @width), (Random @height)

      p.behaviours.push attraction
      p.behaviours.push repulsion
      p.behaviours.push bounds
      p.behaviours.push collide

      collide.pool.push p

      @physics.particles.push p

  ### Initialise the demo (override). ###
  init: (@container, @renderer = new WebGLRenderer()) ->

    # Build the scene.
    @setup @renderer.gl?

    # Give the particles random colours.
    for particle in @physics.particles
      particle.colour ?= Random.item Simulation.COLOURS

    # Add event handlers.
    document.addEventListener 'resize', @resize, false

    # Add to render output to the DOM.
    @container.appendChild @renderer.domElement

    # Prepare the renderer.
    @renderer.mouse = @mouse
    @renderer.init @physics

    # Resize for the sake of the renderer.
    do @resize

    #Dancer
    @kick.on()

    @dancer.load {
      src: AUDIO_FILE
      codecs: CODECS
    }

    @dancer.play()

  ### Handler for window resize event. ###
  resize: (event) =>

    @width = window.innerWidth
    @height = window.innerHeight
    @renderer.setSize @width, @height

  ### Update loop. ###
  step: ->

    stats.begin()

    # Step physics.
    do @physics.step

    # Render every frame for WebGL, or every 3 frames for canvas.
    @renderer.render @physics if @renderer.gl? or ++@counter % 3 is 0

    stats.end()

  ### Clean up after yourself. ###
  destroy: ->

    # Remove event handlers.
    document.removeEventListener 'resize', @resize, false

    # Remove the render output from the DOM.
    try container.removeChild @renderer.domElement
    catch error

    do @renderer.destroy
    do @physics.destroy

    @renderer = null
    @physics = null
    @mouse = null



simulation = new Simulation()
playing = false
container = $('#container')

init = ->
  playing = true
  simulation.init(container.get(0))
  update()

update = ->
  requestAnimationFrame(update)

  simulation.step() if playing && simulation

init()
```

This particular pen works fine. But... When I look at the preview in [my profile](http://codepen.io/fauxnoir/) It shows a blank preview? My other Pens seem fine, it's just this one that doesn't display properly.

Why is this? And what lines of code cause this?

Comment: This looks like an issue with Codepen itself. I would recommend logging an issue here -> http://codepen.io/support/

Comment: This help article may apply: [Turn Off JavaScript in Previews](http://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/turn-off-javascript-in-previews/) "On any page that displays a grid of Pens as live previews… This can be useful if you…accidentally create a Pen with JavaScript that is taking to long to run. Perhaps an infinite loop or a loop with so many iterations it hangs the browser."

Comment: @gfullam: Yes! That could be it. This particular pen generates 800 particles... It hangs a bit.

Comment: Well, in that case I'll post it as an answer so you can have some closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Perhaps a loop with too many iterations causes the preview to hang

This help article may apply: [Turn Off JavaScript in Previews](http://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/turn-off-javascript-in-previews/)

> "On any page that displays a grid of Pens as live previews… This can
>   be useful if you…accidentally create a Pen with JavaScript that is
>   taking to long to run. Perhaps an infinite loop or a loop with so many
>   iterations it hangs the browser."

You'll also notice that after a few seconds your other live previews freeze. This behavior can even be observed on the codepen.io homepage where memory intensive previews freeze after a few seconds while some previews (presumably less memory intensive) continue to animate.

FWIW it appears that the preview, while frozen, *is* showing the first frame of your pen as it appears on page load, which just happens to be a blank white screen. Perhaps a good compromise it to show some static version of the many particles initially so that the preview has something to show.